# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DEPARTMENT_NAME'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have problems on my dropdown function. The dropdown function suppose to get the values from the database. I think the problem is on the sql select command, but I am new to this kind of stuff (asp.net and sql). can someone help me please, thank you in advance.

this is the SQL DataSourceID

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:*****ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 10 
 C.CASE_KEY, C.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, O.OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION AS CHARGE, LAB_CASE, 
   OFFENSE_DATE

   FROM TV_LABCASE C

   INNER JOIN TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE

    INNER JOIN TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE

    ORDER BY CASE_DATE DESC

   "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code for the input fields

```
 <table class="style2" >
    <tr>
        <td class="style3" >Department Case #</td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="False" ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td class="style3">Department</td>
         <td> 
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                  Height="18px" Width="166px" Enabled="False">
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
         <td class="style3">Charge</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                 Height="25px" Width="165px" Enabled="False">
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style3">Lab Case #</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Enabled="False"  ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td class="style3">Incident Report Date</td>
       <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Enabled="False" ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

ASP.NET C#(server-side code)

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=A**SE****D***\MSSQL****;Initial Catalog=****;User 
        ID=****;Password=****";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TV_LABCASE", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_CODE";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "OFFENSE_CODE";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your command query to join `TV_DEPTNAME` table

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select C.*, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME from TV_LABCASE C INNER JOIN TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE, ", cnn);
```

or change your `datasource` to

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_CODE";
DropDownList1.DataBind();


DropDownList2.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
DropDownList2.DataBind();
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "CHARGE";
```

and update your  `asp:SqlDataSource` config

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:*****ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 10 
        C.CASE_KEY, C.DEPARTMENT_CASE_NUMBER, D.DEPARTMENT_NAME, O.OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION AS CHARGE, LAB_CASE, 
        OFFENSE_DATE, C.DEPARTMENT_CODE
        FROM TV_LABCASE C
        INNER JOIN TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE
        INNER JOIN TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE
        ORDER BY C.CASE_DATE DESC"
></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: second answer outputs : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DEPARTMENT_CODE'.

Comment: First answer outputs incorrect syntax

Comment: include also `DropDownList2.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;`

Comment: output: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION'.

Comment: change to `DropDownList2.DataTextField = "CHARGE";`

Comment: thank you so much, i just added C.OFFENSE_CODE after C.DEPARTMENT_CODE so that it can select it also. thanks again

Comment: great. actually you can remove your `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` objects

Answer (score 1):

Code for the input fields enable the value is true. TRY IT

```
<table class="style2" >
    <tr>
        <td class="style3" >Department Case #</td>
        <td> <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="true" ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td class="style3">Department</td>
         <td> 
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                  Height="18px" Width="166px" Enabled="true">
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
         <td class="style3">Charge</td>
         <td>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                 Height="25px" Width="165px" Enabled="true">
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="style3">Lab Case #</td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Enabled="true"  ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td class="style3">Incident Report Date</td>
       <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Enabled="true" ontextchanged="btnCancel_Click"></asp:TextBox></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

ASP.NET C#(server-side code)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection cnn;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=A**SE****D***\MSSQL****;Initial Catalog=****;User 
        ID=****;Password=****";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        cnn.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * from TV_LABCASE C Left join TV_DEPTNAME D ON C.DEPARTMENT_CODE = D.DEPARTMENT_CODE Left join TV_OFFENSE O ON C.OFFENSE_CODE = O.OFFENSE_CODE", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "DEPARTMENT_NAME";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "DEPARTMENT_CODE";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "OFFENSE_DESCRIPTION";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "OFFENSE_CODE";
        DropDownList2.DataBind();


    }
```